# Why in this code,it always return false when it compares string?

Tags: java, palindrome

why does `if(s.equals(b))`  always return false
now my problem has been resolved!!!! **thanks everyone**
It's all because of changing the size of array.

```
 class A {
  // this is the function of plaindrome
  boolean palindrome(int x) {
    // conversion of integer into string
    String s = Integer.toString(x);
    // conversion of string into char array
    char p[] = s.toCharArray();
    int j = 0;
    char t[] = new char[p.length];
    for (int i = (p.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      t[j] = p[i];
      j++;
    }

    String b = new String(t);
    if (s.equals(b)) return true;
    else return false;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    A object = new A();
    object.palindrome(1221);
  }
}
```

Comment: A `void` method can't return. Post real code. Also your `main` does nothing with the `result`, so how do you know it's always false?

Comment: See also `StringBuilder.reverse()`.

Comment: For one thing, `b.length() == 24`, and `s.length()` will never be that large (at most, it will be 11).

Comment: Replace "24" to "p.length" and return "boolean" instead of "void".

Comment: If this were my code, I would set a debugger breakpoint in the line `if (s.equals(b)) return true;` and check the values of `s` and `b` in the debugger.

Comment: @AndyTurner can you please guide how to write my code with proper indents just like you have done for my code??

Comment: thanks everyone!!!i got ur point

Comment: @Pranjal I did it with [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format). But you don't really need a tool to get basic indentation right: indent when you open a `{`, outdent when you close one.

Comment: @AndyTurner okay!!

Answer (score 1):

You are reversing the string through a `char` array allocated with 24 in length. `char` is a primitive in Java and a such is allocated as `\u0000`. When this then gets converted to a String it becomes in your case `1221\u0000\u0000\u0000` which is not the same as `1221`. By initializing t as `new char[p.length]` it should work better.

Comment: So according to you after converting to a string, the remaining characters i.e 20 characters will have null character as \u0000???Am i right? AND if so then why have you mentiones this 1221\u0000\u0000\u0000?only 3 times you have print null

Comment: Yes, the string would have 21 entries of \u0000, I just left out the remainder to conserver space. Char can't be null, references are null but char is a primitive, so you will bascially get the ascii equivalent of null in the string.